# Hover every other element from the list with an exception of the hovered one

Tags: reactjs, loops, sass, hide, styling

I need to hide every other element from the list, but keep the hovered one visible. How can I do that in React? I suppose there's a solution to use loops, but I do not exactly imagine how to implement that on hover state.

```
// ToDo Component

import React from "react";

export default function ToDo({
  item,
  deleteTask,
  taskCompleteStatus,
  hideDeleteBtnsOnHover,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="ToDo">
      {/* ToDo Form */}
      <form className="ToDo__form">
        {/* Label */}
        <label className="ToDo__form__label" htmlFor={`todo-${item.id}`}>
          <div
            className={
              item.complete
                ? "ToDo__form__label__task complete"
                : "ToDo__form__label__task"
            }
          >
            <p>{item.task}</p>
          </div>
          {/* Checkbox*/}
          <div className="ToDo__form__label__checkbox">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={`todo-${item.id}`}
              name="complete"
              checked={item.complete}
              onChange={() => taskCompleteStatus(item.id)}
            />
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </label>
        {/* Delete Button - delete task when clicked*/}
 {/* Delete Button - I need to hide these buttons 
 when one of the ToDo Components is hovered, but keep visible the hovered ToDo Components delete button*/}
        <button
          type="button"
          id={item.id}
          className="ToDo__form__delete-btn"
          onClick={deleteTask}
        >
          <span className="span__1"></span>
          <span className="span__2"></span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just create a style: element:hover { display: block; }, element { display: none; }

Comment: I need to loop through them...It will not work as I intend. I need to hide all elements when one of them is hovered, and keep visible only the hovered element.

Answer (score 1):

See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hooks-rmeldb?file=/src/styles.css).

Let's say you render `ToDo` components in a div with `className = 'container'`.

```
/* Hide all ToDo components when their wrapper is hovered */
.container:hover .ToDo {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Display the hovered ToDo */
.container .ToDo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Ok.But how I'll hide all elements when one of them is hovered?

Comment: `.ToDo__form__delete-btn { display: none; }` Hides all delete buttons. you want to hide other `ToDo` compoonents?

Comment: The elements by default are visible, but, when I hover one of them, I need to hide all the elements with an exception to the hovered element. Then, when I'm not hovering any element, I need to show the elements(the default state) .

Comment: The answer is pretty good by the way, but there are different components, so that should be applied to all of them simultaneously.

Comment: You can use the selector you need instead of `.ToDo`. Replace `.ToDo` classes with the proper selectors.